# Telerik Popup for MVC3 Extension Fails on Windows 2003 Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc

I have a telerik popup window that loads a partial view. This popup works on my laptop but does not work on Windows 2003 Server.
What I noticed when debugging the code on 2003 server is that the  **ActionResult LogOn()**
method continues to get called as if in a loop. This does not happen on my Windows 7 laptop.
The popup window loads but the partial view does not show in the popup. It works fine on my laptop.
Any ideas?

Comment: what is the content of the pop up? do you have anything inside it that you need access for? Also look at the Jquery of it. see if you can debug the view (html) by placing a break point there.

Comment: Nothing is appearing as an error using firebug. The popup loads a form that collects a user name and an email address. It has a button for submit and one for cancel and that is all.  The form allows the user to receive a new password via email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This lead to the solution.

http://bradkingsley.com/mvc3-visual-studio-2010-error-microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-not-implemented/

JScript was not on the server and caused this issue.